# How to remove jQuery Conflict in prototype.js with 1.8.2.jquery.min.js

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, prototype-js, category-products, conflict

i am using 1.8.2.jquery.min.js for slideshow in home page. i have an error in console like this

electronics.html (line 156)
TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function

element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);   **prototype.js (line 5653)**

TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function

element.dispatchEvent(event);                             **prototype.js (line 5734)**

it makes menu drop-down in category page not working.

I have tried jquery noConflict(); in all the way in Magento but it does not clear above bug.
Also, I have tried some more methods from google to clear but it does work properly.
can anyone help me to clear this error?

Comment: show your codes. Where did you include your jquery file. How are you trying to avoid jquery conflict. Be specific

Comment: First Load your 1.8.2.jquery.min.js and then  prototype.js

Comment: Check there may be more than one jquery files included.Remove all and replace by one.

Answer (score 13):

In your `local.xml`:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs" name="jquery" as="jquery">
        <script>jquery-1.10.2.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>noconflict.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

and `noconflict.js` would simply be

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

From there, anywhere you'd use `$` for jQuery, you'd use `$j` instead.

Alternatively, if its just for a slideshow, and I assume you have something similar to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').slideshow();
})
```

you can do the following instead, and all the code within it would operate as normal:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#target').slideshow();
});
```

Comment: I personally prefer using `jQuery(...)`, you never know where your code will end up and it gets sloppy if some people use `$j`, while others use something different.

Comment: @pspahn `$j` is the default in the new 1.9/1.14 rwd framework

Comment: thanks but its not working still i have same error.

Comment: @Karthick what did you try? Do you still need help?